# Arcsde - FME - import data

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I have a problem with the import of data with FME 2012 and ArcSDE 10.
After import, my data are not visibles in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.
My layers are registered in ArcSDE.

I found a solution:
After import, i write this command line:
`sdelayer -o delete -l .....`
and
`sdelayer -o register`

My feature are visible in ArcMap.
Have you a solution to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit FME?

Comment: 32 Bit FME Desktop

Comment: Are you writing your data to existing layers or new? What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the rowid with primary key.
If you have a big number, ArcSDE doesn't draw the feature in ArcMap.
Solution: Convert type column number to integer !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using 32-bit FME in this case and this fact is causing the issue.

FME 2012 SP3/SP4 officially supports ArcGIS 10.1. ArcGIS Server 10.1 **is 64-bit only** and **requires FME 64-bit**. This article outlines some limitations in this configuration.

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/FME-and-ArcGIS-Server-10-1

Solution install
http://www.safe.com/support/support-resources/fme-downloads/64-bit/

Comment: I use ArcSDE 10.1 sp5 and FME Desktop 2012 sp4

Comment: 32-bit FME Desktop will work fine with ArcSDE 10.1 geodatabases. See [Notes on FME and ESRI Versions and Compatibility](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Notes-on-FME-and-ESRI-Versions-and-Compatibility). While it is true that ArcGIS Server 10.1 is 64-bit only, this is actually a separate product from ArcSDE and SDE geodatabases.

Comment: @Julien, did you mean 10.0 SP5? 10.1 is only up to SP1.

Comment: Yes exactly. Arcsde 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the "code" you're running in ArcSDE, it looks like FME isn't registering the layers with ArcSDE properly. By running the delete and then register you're rectifying this by removing the previous registration and then manually creating a new one.

You've not provided enough information to diagnose the problem further (hence everyone asking questions of you).

In theory it should work. This document has basic information about the writer: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Comparison-of-FME-readers-and-writers-for-SDE-and-Geodatabase
Full information about the writer can be found in the *Help -> FME Readers and Writers Reference*.

I can't test this writer, but the table registration code should probably be in the log. Check to compare the code in the log with the code you're using yourself in the ArcSDE console.

---

Note: your tables can only have a single geometry type in them for successful registration